Как проще всего изменить данные таблицы при добавлении элемента через модальное окно?
Мне нужно реализовать добавление новой строки в бд и последующее отображение этой строки в таблице на клиенте. И чтобы все это происходило на одной странице.
В гайде по next js есть пример подобного действия через серверное действие с помощью revalidatePath и redirect, однако добавление и отображение данных в гайде происходит на разных страницах.
Можно ли как-нибудь так же просто это сделать на одной странице? Например вызвать компонент таблицы заново или еще как-нибудь?

Можно. Запрос на добавление, в ответ все нужные записи, сохранили в стор и заново рендер.

вот и вопрос, как заререндерить?

Рендер происходит от изменения состояния переменных(те что с помощью хука useState), либо при изменении props. Значит новое надо сохранить..  вопрос, без вашего кода - теоретический.
